# Launch PDF from IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

My aim is like this:
 1. Save PDF to IsolatedStorage
 2. Launch it from IsolatedStorage

I have tried all codes, but not getting the output.

My PDF document remains blank. I stuck here, don't getting what is wrong with it

See my code.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://aaaaa.com/aaaa");

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;

async void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
  await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

  using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
  {
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
      await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
  }

  StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
  StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync("Test.pdf");

  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct (it's a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight). What application use to read the PDF?
I tried same code with the following link http://phonegap2014.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/phonegap-Windows-Universal-App-contest-final-rules.pdf and the official app "PDF Reader" correctly shows local pdf saved.

Try with same or other link and PDF Reader. ;-)

Comment: I was trying to Launch before it gets completely download. That was the problem. I solved it using Background Downloader. Thanks brother @Vincenzo